# Incorrect XML file produced; Web services

Tags: java, xml, maven, soap, jaxb

I am trying to write an XML file of my EndUser objects. This is required functionality for my web service. I have written the code for this function:

```
public void register(String[][] records) {
    ArrayList<String[]> unregStudents = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    ArrayList<String[]> unregAcademic = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    for (String[] record : records) {
        if (record[1] == "Student") {
            unregStudents.add(record);
        } else if (record[1] == "AcademicStaff") {
            unregAcademic.add(record);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    EndUserArrayList eual = new EndUserArrayList();
    // Assign the EndUsers correct roles
    for (String[] student : unregStudents) {
        int euID = Integer.parseInt(student[0]);
        EndUser eu = new EndUser(euID, Role.Student);
        eual.addEndUser(eu);
    }

    // Assign the EndUsers correct roles
    for (String[] academic : unregAcademic) {
        int euID = Integer.parseInt(academic[0]);
        EndUser eu = new EndUser(euID, Role.AcademicStaff);
        eual.addEndUser(eu);
    }

    // Serialization of End Users.
    if (!new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\eclipse\\workspace\\EndUserService\\src\\main\\java\\EndUserService\\EndUsers.xml").exists()) {

        try {
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\eclipse\\workspace\\EndUserService\\src\\main\\java\\EndUserService\\EndUsers.xml");
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(EndUserArrayList.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.marshal(eual, outputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

This code works for my non web service implementation. When run on the web server I get this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<EndUsers/>
```

The correct XML (created from my non web service implementation):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<EndUsers>
    <EndUser id="0">
        <role>Student</role>
        <moduleArrayList/>
    </EndUser>
    <EndUser id="1">
        <role>Student</role>
        <moduleArrayList>
            <Module academicYear="AY_2019_20">
                <ModuleCode>CSC1022</ModuleCode>
                <Semester>AUT</Semester>
                <Mark markVal="100" notes="P"/>
            </Module>
            <Module academicYear="AY_2019_20">
                <ModuleCode>CSC1022</ModuleCode>
                <Semester>AUT</Semester>
            </Module>
        </moduleArrayList>
    </EndUser>
    <EndUser id="2">
        <role>Student</role>
        <moduleArrayList/>
    </EndUser>
    <EndUser id="3">
        <role>Student</role>
        <moduleArrayList/>
    </EndUser>
    <EndUser id="4">
        <role>Student</role>
        <moduleArrayList/>
    </EndUser>
    <EndUser id="5">
        <role>AcademicStaff</role>
        <moduleArrayList>
            <Module academicYear="AY_2019_20">
                <ModuleCode>CSC1022</ModuleCode>
                <Semester>AUT</Semester>
            </Module>
        </moduleArrayList>
    </EndUser>
    <EndUser id="6">
        <role>AcademicStaff</role>
        <moduleArrayList/>
    </EndUser>
</EndUsers>
```

I am confused as to why their is a difference, as the function is the same in the non-webservice as it is in the web service version.

**CLI call**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Controller controller = new Controller();
    //Hardcoded Student/AcademicStaff here.
    String[] rec1 = {"0","Student"};
    String[] rec2 = {"1","Student"};
    String[] rec3 = {"2","Student"};
    String[] rec4 = {"3","Student"};
    String[] rec5 = {"4","Student"};
    String[] rec6 = {"5","AcademicStaff"};
    String[] rec7 = {"6","AcademicStaff"};
    String[][] endUserList = {rec1,rec2,rec3,rec4,rec5,rec6,rec7};
    controller.batchReg(endUserList);
}
```

**Controller Call**

```
public class Controller {
    public void batchReg(String[][] records){
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/EndUserService/?wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (url == null) {
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
        QName qname = new QName("http://EndUserService/","EndUserServiceImplService");
        System.out.println(url);
        System.out.println("A");
        Service service = Service.create(url,qname);
        System.out.println("B");
        
        QName qport = new QName("http://EndUserService/","EndUserServiceImplPort");
        EndUserService obj = service.getPort( qport,EndUserService.class );
        System.out.println("C");
        obj.register(records);
        System.out.println("Complete!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are useing `==` to compare Strings. Use `equals`! It's sheer luck when the optimizer reuses the String Objects this can give the right results in your 'non-webservice implementation'

Comment: @Turo Thanks mate, I come from a python background so getting use to it!